# Would the acceleration of a model rocket be constant for a constant thrust or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rocket-science

The question is this:

[image: question]

I believe the answer is A as the gravitational field strength becomes lower for larger distances of the object from the earth, but the model answer as as below:

[image: model answer]

Are they completely disregarding that the weight changes?

Comment: The problem statement itself says that the upward thrust is constant, so it seems that the problem itself disregards the weight change.

Comment: Terrible question, not stating "ignore drag force" and "assume constant gravity". Terrible answer mentioning drag, but not accounting for its velocity dependence. You need to find a better textbook.

Comment: This problem ignores the mass lost due to the fuel burning. It also ignores aerodynamic forces. It should at least state those in the problem statement.

Comment: If the rocket rises 100 metres, the fractional change in local gravity is by about 30 ppm (that's 30 parts per million or $3 \times 10^{-5}$) so it can be ignored. Even if the rocket reaches 10 km the gravity change is still small (less than one percent); changing from say $9.8$ m/s$^2$ to $9.77$ m/s$^2$.

Answer (score 0):

In many excersizes in introductory physics it is necessary to make reasonable assumptions or reasonable simmulations in order to get the focus on the point of the problem.  Sometimes a "correct" solution is well beyond the scope of an introductory course.  Unless otherwise stated explicitly, in situations that occur near the Earth gravity is assumed to be constant.  Besides, how much of a change in the gravitational force do you think a model rocket would experience?  And if you want to include the reduction in the force of gravity with height, the acceleration would not change linearly. Similarly, in (c) and (d) the transtion from zero thrust to constant thrust has to be ingnored.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what the question writer was probably thinking:

> I believe the answer is A as the gravitational field strength becomes lower for larger distances of the object from the earth,

The question is about a "model rocket", not a Saturn V or Titan rocket that can reach orbit.

Hobbyist model rockets typically don't reach more than 100 m above ground level. This isn't high enough for the gravitational field strength to reduce significantly. If we're neglecting the reduced mass due to burnt fuel, we should also neglect the smaller effect due to changing strength of gravitation at the altitudes achievable by model rockets.

Also notice that graph (a) shows the acceleration reduced to 0 at t = 0. If this were the case and the mechanism in play were the change in gravity due to altitude, the rocket couldn't ever leave the ground. Therefore (a) can't be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question does say "...if the decrease in mass as the fuel burns is neglected".  For a typical model rocket this is actually not a terrible assumption.  The total mass of fuel in a model rocket engine is only of order 10 g (e.g. an Estes C6-3 engine has about 12 g of fuel) and the rocket being launched with such an engine could easily have a mass of 100 g.  So the fuel is about 10% of the total rocket mass.  Ignoring that loss of mass isn't a fabulous approximation, but it's also not a bad approximation.

As other people have pointed out, the rocket won't go very high (100 m is pretty typical, as @The Photon says) so we don't need to worry about reduction of gravity.

The question is neglecting drag (but doesn't say so...).  It's pretty standard to just neglect drag for the entirety of an introductory physics course, but I do wish question writers would be explicit about it.  In the case of a real model rocket, drag would certainly **not** be negligible.  But none of the answers provided are consistent with including drag.

So, the real question is, given the assumptions (as question says, don't worry about reduced mass.  As question doesn't say, ignore drag.) how would you know that C is correct?  All the forces acting on the rocket before burnout of the engine are constant (we are told the thrust is constant, gravity is approximately constant as long as it doesn't go too high).  So the acceleration should be constant up until the moment when the engine burns out.  That moment when the engine burns out and the acceleration changes is before T since the rocket continues to go up after engine burnout, but it will be slowing down all the way to max height.  So,we should see a constant acceleration up to a some time before T, then a different constant acceleration after that time.  That's what C is showing.

If we were thinking about a reduction in gravity, as you suggest in your justification for why you thought the answer should be A, we wouldn't expect a zero acceleration at t = 0.  We would still expect something positive, but we would expect it to increase after that.

The answers given are targeting several "standard" misconceptions.

- A is targeting people who are confusing v with a (v does increase starting from zero, but a does not).
- B is targeting the same misconception as A, but adding in the confusion of what happens at time T.  Time T is when v switches sign, but nothing special happens to a.
- D is also targeting misconceptions about time T (v switches sign there, but a does nothing special).

So, the question is primarily targeting mixups between velocity and acceleration.